# Can this dress change colour dynamically?

Tags: video, clothing, colors

This [news site](http://pickle.nine.com.au/2016/10/31/10/34/video-of-colour-changing-dress-will-make-you-squeal-with-delight) features a video of a dress changing colours via an iPad app. The news site says:

> Sydney designers Showpo posted a video to YouTube showing off their new ‘colour changing’ dress, and the woman modelling it nearly can’t control herself.

[image: White dress changes to pink]

[image: Pink dress changes to blue]

I've been around the internet a few times and I'm fairly sure this technology doesn't exist. Is this video fake?

Comment: Yes, but it can only switch between blue and black, and white and gold.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

According to a [post on the designer's Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/iloveshowpo/videos/1549491195066774/) (and as reported by [finder.com.au](https://www.finder.com.au/showpo-colour-change-dress-secret)), it's fake:

> Hey guys! So our 'colour changing dress' has garnered a LOT of attention and questions, so here's some more information.... Although we haven’t invented the product *yet*, we think we could soon with your help! If you’re a student and study STEM subjects that is! We're working with Samsung and Questacon to encourage young Australians to set themselves up for success. You can find out more at www.creatorswanted.com :) Samsung Australia Questacon

Comment: "Here's a fake experiment, now go be inspired by that and start a career in science" is probably not a great message to be communicating to society (albeit one that bodes well for skeptics.se's future).

Comment: Quite: the ad copy there borders on the ridiculous; it is puerile

Comment: Yes! This is why you should be studying STEM subjects - to be able to invent clothing that changes colour. Why are we not *funding* this?

Comment: Looks like someone beat them to market by a few decades: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercolor

Comment: @ZachLipton I think that's great communication. _Hey, do you like this thing? Study hard so you can make it happen._ is **way** better than _Go to school just because you have to_.

Comment: To be clear, I'm all for the message of "study this stuff and invent cool new things" whether those things are incredibly practical or not; I just take issue with the deception.

Comment: The ironic thing is that it is already possible to make something like this, for example using: http://cen.acs.org/articles/92/web/2014/08/Flexible-Fibers-Change-Color-Flip.html So if they wanted to they *could* have built this.  But instead they decided to fake it for whatever reason.

Comment: @TheBlackCat: in theory. In reality, this stuff has been hypothesized since 2006, but never implemented in clothing. How would you wire it to connect to every fiber, where would you hide the electronics, what would it all cost...?